# How to replace 1 or 2 with M and F in command line

Tags: awk, command

I have a file with four columns( four fields). One column is sex coded as 1 or 2. How could I use awk command to replace 1 by M and 2 by F?

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output so we're not guessing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '$3=$3==1?"M":"F"' file
```

for example:

```
kent$  echo "a b 1 c
c d 2 x"|awk '$3=$3==1?"M":"F"'
a b M c
c d F x
```

in this example, your 3rd column is `1 or 2`, you just change the `$3` to the right column index.

It is always good to show an example of your input, also with expected output.